# React, NextJS, Pusher multiple responses returned for every request

Tags: reactjs, next.js, pusher

I have been trying to make my application fetch new data every time a Pusher response is received, but the problem now is that for every new response, the response count seems to be higher by 1 and so it the fetch call...
For example for the first time that I request new data when I receive a Pusher response I call my API 1 time, the second time I receive 2 Pusher responses then 3 and so on and it slows down my performance quite a lot...
Can anyone explain to me what seems to be the problem?

```
useEffect(() => {
    //Pusher.logToConsole = true;
    var pusher = new Pusher("pusherID", {
      cluster: "eu",
    });
    const channel = pusher.subscribe("pusher-channel");
    channel.bind("", function (data) {
      console.log(data); //log pusher response so I know how many are received
      mutate("data"); //fetch data from API
    });
  });
```

If I check my Pusher dashboard I have a lot connections made and messages sent and I'm only using one device to do that so this probably means that this one device is connecting multiple times and sending multiple messages which is really bad...

Comment: So you want that useEffect only run once or you want to run useEffect based on dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a subscription system you would normally want to only subscribe once and when your component is ready, this usually happens on first `useEffect` call and it is always a good idea to save a reference to service you are calling in top level of your component(within state or ref object).

Your issue is that your `useEffect` doesn't have any dependency so it basically runs every time your component rerenders. If you put empty dependency array this could solve your problem.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const pusher = new Pusher("pusherID", {
    cluster: "eu",
  });
  const channel = pusher.subscribe("pusher-channel");
  channel.bind("", function (data) {
    mutate("data"); //fetch data from API
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: thank you very much that was the issue, my mistake to not even recognise that